# ipad pdf unreadable text

Tags: pdf, ipad, quartz-2d

I'm using the Quartz 2d apis to display a pdf document in an iPad app I am currently working on, however the text shows up real funky and is unreadable.  The text shows up fine on my laptop so its not an issue with the pdf document itself as far as I know.  I'm not sure why the document is displaying like this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  A link to an image which shows the text is below.

Also, I tried to just open the pdf in safari on the iPad and i got the same results with the funky text. So I'm not sure why the iPad can't display this document.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e7b5766199.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e7b5766199.png)

Comment: hi marchinram..
did u get any sol for your problem? i am also facing same issue.
could please let me know if you are able to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes but its not a real solution, I just had the producer of the pdf remake it without the fonts embedded.  So you can't select the text or anything, the problem is now that when you zoom in it pixelizes like an image.  But my client didn't mind.  It would appear however that the problem is that the font is not on the iPad.  You can use custom fonts for labels and text fields but I guess it doesn't work with pdfs.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and its really becoming a pain. I use alot of PDF versions of tech books EF/C#/.NET 4 and they are all coming out like the above example, all are fine on PC Acrobat. This is turning my iPad "book reader" into a door stop. Did you find a fix? :)

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way to add fonts to the iPad.  You can use custom fonts in apps you develop but this didn't seem to work with the pdf when i drew it with core graphics. Apple should add this, seems obvious if there gonna have a pdf reader (iBooks).

Comment: I am having a similar problem with VoucherPress (plugin for WP), through my research there seems to be a problem with the way Apple devices handle Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong font substitution? There's probably a non-embedded font that you have on your laptop but the iPad doesn't have. On PC acrobat reader you can look in properties, fonts to see - I'm not sure what the Mac equivalent is. If that's it, you can open the document in Acrobat on your Mac and re-save it with the font embedded.

If that isn't it, you might have found a bug in the iPad PDF libraries dealing with a particular font or font subset type - there's lots of variations. You can again see how the font is stored in Acrobat Reader or you might get more information from pdffonts in the xpdf package (you may have to compile this yourself - I'm not sure of availability on Macs). Again you may be able to resave the document in Acrobat embedding the font in a different way - I'm less sure about this one.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, do you know if there is a way to "flatten" the pdf document so the text is not selectable but will be able to be displayed, kinda like making it into a graphic rather than a document

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Acrobat expert - I've worked through similar problems with pdf2swf, that's all. I expect there would be, though - perhaps in the 'preflight' menu?